# Select all check boxes in specific tbody using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that gets dynamically populated.

The main table will have 3 `<tbody>` sections in it and rows in each one.

Each row will have a checkbox in it.

What I want to do is use a jquery selector that matches the `<tbody>` id. The id is also dynamically created so it is not a constant value but uses a variable.

The jquery I am trying to use is this:

```
$(":input[id$='_ErrorCheckbox']").click(function () {
        var wbId = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[0].toString().trim();

        $('tbody#' + wbId + ' _ErrorVisits tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
```

I also tried using this statement to grab the rows in that `<tbody>` but it did not work (threw an unknown syntax error):

```
$('tbody[id$=' + wbId + ' _ErrorVisits] tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

The first method above, does not throw any errors but does not select anything.

What is the correct way to use jquery selectors to grab a specific `<tbody>` element using its id?

Edit: 
Here is the html table output:

```
<table id="workbookTable_25116" cellpadding="10">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><input type="checkbox" id="25116 _SelectAllCheckbox"></th><th>Visit Timepoint</th><th>Visit Information</th><th>Notifications/Errors</th><th>Preview SQC Analysis</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="25116 _ErrorVisits">
                        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="25116 _ErrorCheckbox"></td><td><b>Visits in Error</b></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr style="background-color: red;"><td><input type="checkbox" id="9be44178-7273-4057-9607-acb135114b39 _25116 _Checkbox" name="visit_cb"></td><td>Week 8</td><td>1008-001, Week 8, 14005_MRI_Femur v1.0</td><td>This visit has a task in Error status!</td><td><input type="button" id="9be44178-7273-4057-9607-acb135114b39 _25116 _ResetTaskButton" value="Reset Task"></td></tr><tr style="background-color: red;"><td><input type="checkbox" id="367e7f6a-ec3a-476f-a1e3-b3eecf18db8b _25116 _Checkbox" name="visit_cb"></td><td>Week 16</td><td>1008-001, Week 16, 14005_MRI_Femur v1.0</td><td>This visit has a task in Error status!</td><td><input type="button" id="367e7f6a-ec3a-476f-a1e3-b3eecf18db8b _25116 _ResetTaskButton" value="Reset Task"></td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tbody id="25116 _NotPreviouslySQCvisits">
                        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="25116 _NotSQCCheckbox"></td><td><b>First Time SQC Visits</b></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr style="background-color: yellow;"><td><input type="checkbox" id="d38bc66a-561e-4a12-9d95-4979eb3e9b9b _25116 _Checkbox" name="visit_cb"></td><td>Week 4</td><td>1008-001, Week 4, 14005_MRI_Femur v1.0</td><td></td><td><input type="button" id="d38bc66a-561e-4a12-9d95-4979eb3e9b9b _25116 _PreviewButton" value="SQC Analysis Preview"></td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tbody id="25116 _PreSQCvisits">
                        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="25116 _PreSQCCheckbox"></td><td><b>Previously SQC Visits</b></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr style="background-color: greenyellow;"><td><input type="checkbox" id="25d62e5f-b69d-4f87-aaaa-09c44e06f1cb _25116 _Checkbox" name="visit_cb"></td><td>Week 12</td><td>1008-001, Week 12, 14005_MRI_Femur v1.0</td><td></td><td><input type="button" id="25d62e5f-b69d-4f87-aaaa-09c44e06f1cb _25116 _PreviewButton" value="SQC Analysis Preview"></td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Edit:
Solution found, needed quotes around id. See my answer below for code.
Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: paste your code on fiddle

Comment: Show us the html table output

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$('tbody#' + wbId + '_ErrorVisits...`, without the leading space? I doubt you have `<_ErrorVisits>` elements in your page.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I am using asp.net mvc, and the wbId variable is added using a razor expression (@Model). The space is needed.

Comment: @RXC, that space results in an incorrect selector. Why is it needed exactly?

Comment: Since you are using asp.net mvc and seem to have a handle on the HTML that arrives at the browser, wouldn't it be much easier to add a class to all checkboxes in the relevant tbody section within the Razor view? The name of the class can be any user-defined string - e.g. rxcCheckbox. Then the jquery selection process would be very straightforward and standard.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - The id is built like this: `id="@wb.Id _Checkbox"` I need the space in there or else the razor expression will look for a property called Id_Checkbox.

Comment: Okay, you have spaces in your ids. These are not valid in any version of HTML I know of. You may try to escape them by prefixing them with two backslashes or by using `"[id='" + wbId + " _ErrorVisits']"`, but I would just get rid of them if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, but it turns out I was missing quotes around the id selector.

Here is the final jquery code:

```
$("tbody[id$='" + wbId + " _ErrorVisits'] tr td input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

Quotes needed to be placed around the id to prevent a syntax error and because the id had spaces in it.

Comment: That's a workaround or a quick fix not a solution. ID's should not have spaces in them.

Comment: @user3558931 - I agree with that, but in asp mvc, I am grabbing model data and appending text to it like this: `id="@wb.Id _Checkbox"` I need the space in there or else the razor expression will look for a property called wb.Id_Checkbox. I will look into how to avoid those spaces to conform the html standards.

Answer (score 4):

The follow line should be changed:

```
$('tbody[id$=' + wbId + ' _ErrorVisits] tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

To:

```
$('tbody[id$=' + wbId + '_ErrorVisits] tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

**THAT IS**: replace `' _ErrorVisits]` with `'_ErrorVisits]`.

**NOTE:**   I would not advise on the use of `id's` with spaces but the spaces can be escaped as follows as a ***quick fix***:

Replace `wbId` with `wbId.replace(/ /g, '\\\\ ')`

**The ideal solution is to fix the ids to remove spaces.**

Comment: @Sudharsan, removed the leading space before `_ErrorVisits`. However, the questioner [reveals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612175/select-all-check-boxes-in-specific-tbody-using-jquery#comment38138437_24612175) their `id` attributes *do* contain spaces, so that won't solve their problem.